# Grafana draws line between first an last point

Tags: grafana

Why is grafana drawing a line between first and last point?
I have searched between all the display properties but I don't find why.
The data is get from mongodb query if it could be key.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You didn't provide reproducible exampe, so every answer will be only a guess. My guess: data are not sorted by time.

Answer (score 0):

It was exactly what @Jan Garaj said in his comment. I had data not sorted by time in fact I had also repeated dates.